# Is there any benefit to split Get() into Has() and Get() of containers?

Tags: c++, search, stl, containers

Say I have a `vector<MyClass>`, and a `GetMyClass()`, like:

```
std::vector<MyClass> mcs; // assume mcs has some elements...

MyClass* GetMyClass()
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mcs.begin(), mcs.end(), 
    [](const MyClass& mc)
    {
        return mc.condition() == true;
    });

    if (it == mcs.end())
        return nullptr;
    else
        return &(*it);
}
```

This is very conventional, the user calls it and check the return value is `nullptr` or not. But bad things happen if the user forgot to check. The `nullptr` check is annoying, and is not always happening. Besides, this function is kind-of a mix of both **checking** (if there is any valid `MyClass`) and **getting** (one `MyClass`).

*P.S. `MyClass.condition() == true;` is just a simplification, real case could be more complicated.*

So I came across to make 2 functions:

```
bool HasMyClass()
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mcs.begin(), mcs.end(), 
    [](const MyClass& mc)
    {
        return mc.condition() == true;
    });

    return (it == mcs.end());
}

MyClass& GetMyClass()
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mcs.begin(), mcs.end(), 
    [](const MyClass& mc)
    {
        return mc.condition() == true;
    });

    return (*it);
}
```

If the user wants to know the existence of `MyClass` then he calls `HasMyClass()`;
If the user wants to get one `MyClass` and is very sure there must be one, then he calls `GetMyClass()` directly. If the user wants one `MyClass` but is not sure, then he calls both of them.

To eliminate code duplication and to avoid redundant execution, I modify it to be:

```
std::vector<MyClass> mcs; // assume mcs has some elements...
// std::vector<MyClass>::iterator temp; // originally this
MyClass* temp = nullptr; // changed to this according to Hsi-Hung Shih's advice

bool HasMyClass()
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mcs.begin(), mcs.end(), 
    [](const MyClass& mc)
    {
        return mc.condition() == true;
    });

    if (it == mcs.end())
    {
        temp = nullptr;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = &(*it);
        return true;
    }
}

MyClass& GetMyClass()
{
    if (temp == nullptr)
    {
        HasMyClass();
    }

    MyClass& mc = (*temp);
    temp = nullptr;
    return mc;
}
```

**My question is:**

**Is there any benefit to make an additional `Has()` function?**

**If so, will this ease any burden of the user? Will this make the intention of code use more clear? Is the extra complication worth it?**

Thanks!

Comment: `return MyClass.condition() == true;`?? do you mean `return mc.condition() == true;`

Comment: If the user is unsure and calls both, then the search is performed twice, whereas before it was only performed once. Also, you start by postulating a user that is unsure, but fails to check the return value for `nullptr`. Why do you believe that the very same user won't fail to call `Has()`?

Comment: you miss some parenthesis at if (temp == mcs.end()

Comment: `return &(*it);` return address of local variable which is `UB`

Comment: @billz: False. `&(*it)` is an address of an element inside the vector. You are thinking of `&it`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In the worst case that the value does not exist, and by calling both, the search performed twice, but in other cases it's only once. And I think the worst case should not happen. And yes, that user can fail to call `Has()`, but I am wondering if `Has()` do better for other "good" users...

Comment: If you want to protect careless users, then throw an exception when they try to get an element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise keeping the original implementation of `GetMyClass`. I would add `HasMyClass` as a convenience function for those cases where that's the only information needed to fork.
You can implement `HasMyClass` by using `GetMyClass`. It's a trivial implementation.

```
bool HasMyClass()
{
    return (GetMyClass() != nullptr);
}
```

If a function uses,

```
if ( HasMyClass() )
{
    MyClass* c = GetMyClass();
}
```

There will be two searches. This is a bad use of the functions but you can't stop them.

A better use of `HasMyClass` is:

```
if ( HasMyClass() )
{
  // Follow path 1 (does not involve call to GetMyClass)
}
else
{
  // Follow path 2 (does not involve call to GetMyClass either)
}
```

Comment: But usually `HasMyClass()` would bring on `GetMyClass()`, that's why I try to avoid the two searches with the help of `temp` iterator, so that one could call `if (!HasMyClass()) return; MyClass* c = GetMyClass(); c->DoSomething();` without suffering from two searches.

Comment: @MarsonMao, you can do that. However, storing the iterator outside the functions as global variable is not a good design decision.

Comment: Yeah I know, actually the vector and iterator and these methods would be wrapped in a class; the vector and iterator would be private members. I put them as global just for simplicity.

Comment: @MarsonMao, that won't so bad, then.

Answer (score 0):

> and is very sure there must be one

Gives already the answer: If you can not be sure, you can not handle the return value without checking.

But this kind of programming looks like an old posix interface where every retval must be checked. In c++ you have a lot more functionality from the stl without writing such code self. I would advice you to have a look in `<algorithm>`. Think about functor pattern, where you directly give the action to the search function. Take a look at `for_each` and others.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/

Or simply all:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

I believe you can do a lot with stl functionality. Writing own search functions, accessing them, checking retvals and do something with the value/iterator must normally not be done by hand crafted code.

The second attempt could be throwing of exceptions like `throw NotFound_t();`

Comment: Yes, checking retval is very annoying. But I dont quite understand why should I use `for_each` in this case, could you give me some hint, please?

Answer (score 0):

A usual implementation is to change the interface to pass the pointer as a parameter and to return whether or not the object was found :

```
bool TryGetMyClass(MyClass* ptr)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(mcs.begin(), mcs.end(), 
    [](const MyClass& mc)
    {
        return mc.condition() == true;
    });

    if (it == mcs.end())
    { 
       ptr = nullptr;
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       ptr = &(*it);
       return true;
    }
}
```

Usage example :

```
if(TryGetMyClass(ptr))
  ... // Ok, ptr not null
else
  ... // Handle null pointer
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will study that. Also thanks for the `unique_ptr` suggestion.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I typed to quick, smart ptr reflex... note removed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checking returned value for potential failure is common API design, so the programmers are supposed to be familiar with it and can use it with ease. If they forget to check it, they will know when they dereference it.

You can throw exception when none is found, but finding nothing in a container is usually not an exceptional thing, and it had better not throw.

By the way, your code is also dangerous, because the iterator "temp" could be invalid after your previous find. It could result from item being removed from the vector. Function with unclear side effects is very bad.

In sum, make your API familiar to people. Don't complicate the code just to make it look cute, like allowing people to not checking the return value for potential failure.

**Edit**

If your data could be nullptr, you can just define a data class to return, in which it could indicate failure state. If you are lazy, you could use std::pair to do this.

```
struct Data {
    bool is_failed;
    MyClass* data;
};
```

Comment: You're right, I should use `MyClass*` for `temp`, not iterator. But what I'm trying to achieve is for the convenience of the user, I think checking the return value is annoying and redundant in many cases. Like Klaus said: "But this kind of programming looks like an old posix interface where every retval must be checked". If one has to check the return value, then it should be as clear as possible, like a `bool` for "has, or not" is very straightforward.

Comment: Whereas a `nullptr` for "has, or not" is not straightforward enough; what if the container does allow `nullptr` to be stored in it?

Comment: Yes I know it, that pattern is great, I use that pattern in some cases. But in other cases one would want to halt execution immediately (to make things simpler), but not a sequence calls of no-actions. So a check would help a lot.

Comment: If your HasMyClass() cannot find anything in the vector, what will happen when the user call GetMyClass()? It crashes... Instead of letting the user crash when they dereference the nullptr, you just let it crash inside your own function. Is it any better?

Comment: If you really want to "halt execution" immediately, it must be an exceptional situation. If so, just throw an exception.

Comment: using MyClass* for temp does not solve anything. What if your MyClass object is already removed? What if that object's condition is no longer met? If you call GetMyClass you'll expect to get an object reference that satisfy the condition at the moment that function is called. Using a cached value without checking the condition again make this function incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58307/discussion-between-hsi-hung-shih-and-marson-mao).

Comment: Sorry, I mean "return" or "stop further function calls" instead of "halt execution". The program doesnt need to stop (exit), it just skip some codes. What I mean is like: `If (!HasC()) return; C* c = GetC(); c->Do();`

Comment: I understand your concern, the container could be modified between `Has` and `Get`, but in the common sense these 2 calls should be consecutive, so there should be no modifications involved.

Comment: You either call like `if (!HasC()) return; C* c = GetC();` or directly call `C* c = GetC();` (if you know `c` must be there).

Comment: I understand you want to prevent searching twice with cacheing the value, but for programmers that expect your function to have no side-effects will also suspect calling "has + find" will search twice. In the end, they will still check GetC()'s return value and avoid calling HasC().

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, what these functions show is that you're just not achieving anything by wrapping STL methods. Those already have a well-established pattern to communicate "not found", and C++ programmers are already familiar with that. Your method is confusing even to you.

Instead, what you should do is provide decent predicates for use in `std::find`.

Comment: Did you mean that the lambda I provided to `find_if` is not good enough? Could you please give some example? Thanks!

Comment: @MarsonMao: I assumed that was a simplification for the sake of the question. I'd use `std::mem_fun(&MyClass::condition)`, or perhaps even a free function `bool condition(MyClass const&)`.

Comment: Yes it's a simplification. An use case can be find `MyClass` by some `id`, then the lambda can test if `mc.id() == id`. Is this making more sense? But I still cant understand what's the point about predicate? I mean I still have to return `MyClass`, right? Did you mean that I should return `MyClass` without providing `GetMyClass()` at all?

Comment: @MarsonMao: I mean that you shouldn't even have a function  `GetMyClass`. Just call `std::find_if`. And you don't need a wrapper for `mc.id()==someId`, that's clear enough as a lambda. Custom predicates may be useful for things like `mc.condition1() && !mc.condition2() && (mc.id() & mc.mask()) == someID`

Comment: I see. So you suggest that every call site should directly write `find_if` instead of calling `GetMyClass`? But wouldnt that be a little too redundant? I mean, isnt `MyClass& mc = GetMyClassManager().GetMyClass(someID)` easier than `MyClass& ms = *(std::find_if(GetMyClassManager().GetMyClasses().begin(), GetMyClassManager().GetMyClasses().end(), [](MyClass& mc){return mc.id() == someID;})`? And even if I want to use `std::find_if` directly, I have to store the lambda by `std::function` somewhere, like inside `MyClassManager`, right?

Comment: @MarsonMao: TBH a lot of the verbiage comes from your `ClassManager`, which is more Java than C++ style. I'd just have a `std::vector<MyClass> MyObjects`, so I'd write `*find_if(begin(MyObjects), end(MyObjects), [someID](MyClass& mc){return mc.id() == someID;});` (You don't need `std::` due to ADL). Also, no need to store the lambda somewhere. It's created in-place, when needed, as needed.

Comment: The manager is there to perform actions like create, destroy, get, ...etc, and to hide the raw `vector` from user. Also the manager could have some more member variable and methods to provide some necessary features, so it is possibly more than a plain `vector`. I suppose this is a common use case? I know the lambda is created in-place, but if I need to do the `someID` test many times, won't these in-place lambdas cause code duplication?

Comment: P.S. What's the advantage of using `begin(objs)` rather than `objs.begin()`? I looked up cplusplus.com and can only think of it can deal with plain array.

Comment: @MarsonMao: Re code duplication, no - it's small and will be inlined - the actual function call would be bigger. Re begin(objs), it's a free function which allows retrofitting to other class libraries (e.g. MFC)

Comment: Thanks for introducing `begin()`. I mean copy-pasting `*find_if(begin(MyObjects), end(MyObjects), [someID](MyClass& mc){return mc.id() == someID;});` everywhere in the code is a duplication for human.